# How to add a variable in javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pretty sure its a duplicate but I dont find any answer in other post "relative" plus I'm pretty new to Js so dont be too harsh pls :/

I'm creating a simple function in Js/jQuery for resuming too long text.
I've done it; it works but now I want to use it with a variable (the number of characters) I specifically set when I call it.

Something like `resume(30)` while mean if the text is higher than 30 characters resume it after them.

Here Is what I've got so far : ( You can change nbChar by a value )

```
var nbChar;
function resume(nbChar) {
    $('.resume').each(function () {
        var text = $(this).text();
        if (text.length > nbChar) {
            var less = text.slice(0, nbChar) + '<span class="showMore">...</span>';
            $(this).html(less);

            $(this).data('content', text + '<br/><br/><span class="showLess"> Cacher</span>')
            $(this).data('less', less)
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0yps2b90/) if this could help you answer me.

Any help would be gladly accepted, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works fine, after fixing:

- `<div class=".resume">` should be `<div class="resume">`
- Line 22 `});` should be `}`
- include jQuery library in jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/0yps2b90/1/

Comment: Hum ok so it is an internal problem. Thank you anyway :)